# Why is the ProductInstance Database empty?

Tags: moryx

I want to use the ProductInstance information for data analysis.

The ProductInstance Database is empty after production. The first Activity implements IInstanceModificationActivity with the ModificationType `Created`. Because of this the ProductInstances should be created automatically after the first activty. But it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your ProductInstance strategy in the CommandCenter=>ProductManager=>Configuration. To make sure you don't have the **SkipInstancesStrategy** as the strategy for you product instance.